PHP addChild function misssing the namespace from the xml
Hoping someone can shed some light on why this is happening.
I've used the exact same syntax elsewhere in my code without any issues, but for some reason this isn't working:
$sale = $xml->addChild('sale', null, 'http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/simple');

In my code I have the following:
$sale = $xml->addChild('sale', null, 'http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/simple');
$sale->addChild('saleSummary', null, 'http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/base');
$sale->addChild('description', $orderDescription);
$sale->addChild('amountInMinorUnits', intval($order->get_total() * 100));

which is supposed to output this XML:
<sale xmlns="http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/simple">
   <saleSummary xmlns="http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/base"/>
   <description>Order from Payment Portal</description>
   <amountInMinorUnits>2000</amountInMinorUnits>
</sale>

but is outputting this...
<sale>
   <saleSummary xmlns="http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/base"/>
   <description>Order from Payment Portal</description>
   <amountInMinorUnits>2000</amountInMinorUnits>
</sale>

The namespace is missing from the \<sale\> element.

A quick test shows that it is working as expected, so my assumption is that something somewhere else is causing the issue.

How do you initialize the $xml variable and serialize the fragment? $xml has to be an SimpleXMLElement instance representing an XML element node. The properties of that node can influence the descendant nodes.

I actually found a way to do it not long after posting this question. For reference this is the solution
        $sale = $xml->addChild('sale');
        $sale->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/simple');

        // Add <saleSummary> element with its namespace
        $saleSummary = $sale->addChild('saleSummary', null, 'http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/base');
        $saleSummary->addChild('description', $orderDescription);
        $saleSummary->addChild('amountInMinorUnits', intval($order->get_total() * 100));


Just to be clear, this also changes the structure and does not match your requested output anymore. ``descriptionandamountInMinorUnitsare now children ofsaleSummary`, instead of siblings of it. You absolutely might still be able to use this, I just think it is important to note. https://3v4l.org/TaNnb#v8.3.11

This is the output im getting with the new approach
<sale xmlns="http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/simple">
    <saleSummary xmlns="http://www.capita-software-services.com/scp/base">
        <description>Order from Payment Portal 8</description>
        <amountInMinorUnits>4800</amountInMinorUnits>
    </saleSummary>
</sale>


Yes, I know, that's literally what my example showed. My point was that in your original question you asked for something else, and your answer does not provide what you asked for. That's fine, this is your code, you can do whatever you want, I'm just pointing this out. If someone in the future has your exact problem and finds your question, the answer is "to fix this I needed to change my XML to this".

Another pitfall is that the sale node is created without a namespace (aka the empty namespace), setting the xmlns attribute will not change the namespace of the node. However it is serialized to the same output as a node with the namespace. So it will behave differently before and after serialize/parse: https://3v4l.org/8uE0I#v8.3.11
